# Creating parallax background effect from knockout text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a parallax background effect with some knockout text. I am facing two issues:

1. The parallax effect does not work at all when `background-size: contain;` is set.
2. The parallax effect, for whatever reason, does not work outside of Codepen - when scaled up fully in chrome, the effect disappears and behaves exactly as if the background is stuck to your mouse...I am not sure if this is a scaling issue or issue with chrome and my method.

Here is my code:

```js
(function() {
  // Add event listener
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", parallax);
  const elem = document.querySelector("#text");
  // Magic happens here
  function parallax(e) {
    let _w = window.innerWidth / 2;
    let _h = window.innerHeight / 2;
    let _mouseX = e.clientX;
    let _mouseY = e.clientY;
    let _depth1 = `${50 - (_mouseX - _w) * 0.01}% ${50 - (_mouseY - _h) * 0.01}%`;
    let _depth2 = `${50 - (_mouseX - _w) * 0.02}% ${50 - (_mouseY - _h) * 0.02}%`;
    let _depth3 = `${50 - (_mouseX - _w) * 0.06}% ${50 - (_mouseY - _h) * 0.06}%`;
    let x = `${_depth3}, ${_depth2}, ${_depth1}`;
    console.log(x);
    elem.style.backgroundPosition = x;
  }

})();
```

```css
.background {
  background: #000;
}

#text {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101162946-4377e57745c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1957&q=80");
  /*background-size: contain;*/
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 8vw;
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  <h1 id="text"><b>Galaxy</b></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. For me I can see the parallax effect working on a full screen tab. (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, Firefox 99). For me, the background galaxy image seems to move with my mouse cursor. Is that what is intended? Or do you want the background image to move on scrolling rather than mouse cursor position?

Comment: Yes, I can also run it full screen inside of codepen and it behaves as intended. If the code is placed inside a html/css/js file locally, and ran in chrome, it no longer works. The background is supposed to move when your cursor moves, but as a parallax effect (ie when you move the mouse right, the image moves left non linearly) In chrome the image moves exactly with your mouse.

Comment: What is the expected result? Do you want the background image to move with cursor position, or with the scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be that it depends on the size of the image, which it seems must be smaller than the container (in this case the entire screen/body) in order for this to work.

The image I was using in the above codepen was different to the image I was using in my local instance. To make it behave correctly, I simply applied `background-size: 50%;` to my much larger local background image so that it behaves more like the smaller background image used in the codepen.